# Como organizar o corpo do HTML na tela com CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, front-end, webdesign

Eu fiz um cabeçalho e um menu lateral retrátil, mas eu não consigo agora organizar o corpo do site ao lado do menu, ele fica sempre em baixo e se eu der float left e right ele fica ocupando 10% do tamanho da tela e grudado no lado direito.

HTML e CSS

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
/*menu*/

#menu-lateral {
  width: 250px;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(-250px, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-250px, 0, 0);
  -ms-ransform: translate3d(-250px, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(-250px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-250px, 0, 0);
  transition: ease 1;
}
.toggleMenu {
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
}
main {}
/*barra de cabeçalho*/

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}
/*config do corpo da pag*/

.home-wrapper {
  background-color: gainsboro;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
-Edit- A pedidos,
o JS var clique=document.getElementById("btn-menu");
 var menuLateral=document.getElementById("menu-lateral");
 clique.onclick=function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  menuLateral.classList.toggle('toggleMenu');
}
;

}
);
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="home-wrapper">
    <header>
      <div class="btn-header">
        <a href="#" id="btn-menu">
          <img src="img/menu55.png">
          <img src="img/icone_logo.png">
          <p>Home</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </header>
    <aside id="menu-lateral">
      <div class="menu-wrapper">
        <div id="menu">
          <div class="nome-cargo-titulo">
            <h3 class="nome-titulo">nome</h3>
            <h4 class="cargo-titulo">cargo<h4>
                        </div>
                            <div class="divisoria-menu"><p></p></div>
                            <ul class="box">     
                                <li><a href="#">Acesso </a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Ação </a></li>
                                <li ><a href="#">Lançamento</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="#">Lançamento</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Lançamento</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Saldo</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div> <!-- /#menu -->
                    </div>    
                </aside>
                <main>
                <p>aosihdasoidasoihafasf</p>    
                </main>
                </div>
            <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
           </body>
```

Resumindo: O `aside` fica a esquerda e é retratil, e o  `<section>` é o corpo do site. No momento o section está indo pra baixo de todo conteúdo da página e preciso que ele ocupe o espaço ao lado do menu(à direita).

Tela do site:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

Fiz um esboço rapidão. Veja...

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn-menu').click(function(){
     $("#menu-lateral").toggleClass('toggleMenu');
     $('main').toggleClass('vai');
    });
   });
```

```css
 html, body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
  }
  body {
      text-align: center;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  }
  /*menu*/
  #menu-lateral {
      width: 0%;
      background: #FFF;
      height: calc(100% - 40px);
      -moz-transform: translate3d(-250px, 0, 0);
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(-250px, 0, 0);
      -ms-ransform: translate3d(-250px, 0, 0);
      -o-transform: translate3d(-250px, 0, 0);
      transform: translate3d(-250px, 0, 0);
      transition: all 1s ease;  
      float: left;  
  }
  .toggleMenu {
   width: 20%;
      max-width: 250px;
   
      -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)  !important;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)  !important;
      -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)  !important;
      -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)  !important;
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)  !important;
  }
  main {
   float: right;
   width: 95%;
   background: #C7C7C7;
   height: 100%;
   transition: all 1s ease;
  }
  /*barra de cabeçalho*/
  header{ 
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: #FF0;
      text-align: left;
      text-indent: 10px;
  }
  /*config do corpo da pag*/
  .home-wrapper{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%; 
  }
  ul.box{
   margin:0;
   padding; 0;
  }
  ul.box li{
   list-style: none;
   font-size: 14px;
   font-family: 'Verdana';
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
  .vai{
   width: 80%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

  <head>

  
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="home-wrapper">
       <header>
           <div class="btn-header">
               <a href="#" id="btn-menu">
                |||||||
               <p>Home</p></a>
           </div>    
       </header>
       <aside  id="menu-lateral">
           <div class="menu-wrapper">
               <div id="menu">
               <div class="nome-cargo-titulo">
               <h3 class="nome-titulo">nome</h3>
               <h4 class="cargo-titulo">cargo</h4>
               </div>
                   <div class="divisoria-menu"><p></p></div>
                   <ul class="box">                    
                       <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                   </ul>
               </div> <!-- /#menu -->
           </div>    
       </aside>
       <main>
        <p>aosihdasoidasoihafasf</p>    
       </main>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: eu fiz isso e deu certo, mas ele bugou a animação do menu. Agora ele aparece de cara em vez de ser puxado pro lado como antes...

Comment: O que tem no seu script.js ? É a animação do menu ? Se sim, dá para fazer com CSS mesmo. Porquê eu não vi nenhum Hover no Menu. Pelo que vi, pelo JS você faz um toggleClass da class .toggleMenu no CSS.

Comment: editei ali, sim é somente isso que foi feito

Comment: Veja o código que coloquei na edição da minha resposta. Você não precisa de um script JS para executar a função de aparecer o menu.

Comment: eu não entendi esse hover menu, pq quando eu clico no botão o menu n empurra o botão pro lado, logo o mouse n fica em cima dele e em celulares e tablets n iria funcionar(eu acho..) e n funcionou aqui seu código :/

Comment: Ha Siiim! Então, é que aqui eu não tenho a imagem, nem percebi que tinha um ícone que empurrava o menu. Então realmente você precisa de um script JS. Me desculpe. Vou editar meu código.

Comment: Ah agora eu entendi, my bad, só que eu preciso que o meu venha com o click no botão pq esse site será usado somente em celulares e tablets

Comment: Postei ali uma imagem censurada de como tem q ficar kk

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22929/discussion-between-diego-souza-and-andrey-hartung).

Comment: estou na sala de bate-papo!

Comment: @AndreyHartung refiz minha resposta. Salve num arquivo separado e veja o que eu fiz... pra você ter uma ideia.

Comment: parceiro, aqui não está funcionando... é isso aqui mesmo ou eu fiz uma cagada? http://pastebin.com/0qD2Uk6t

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t3219ehn/ - Se liga nesse LINK.

Comment: Parceiro, se importa de entrar no bate-papo pra eu poder conversar contigo?